# A bug with high precision

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, machine-precision

Consider the following two numbers:

```
num1=0.0006000000000000001`;
num2=0.0006000000000000003`;
```

`num2` appeared from `num1` as a result of some compiled code with `RuntimeOptions->"Speed"`.

Their direct comparison returns

```
num1==num2
```

> True

However,

```
{num1, num2} // DeleteDuplicates
```

keeps both the numbers.

Why do these two operations work at different precision levels?

P.S. Mathematica 13.2 on Windows 11.

Comment: To be clear, this is not a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau : formally, yes. But in practice, I spent a lot of time trying to uncover errors in my code because of this mismatch.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because  default `DeleteDuplicates` uses `===` and not `==` (i.e `SameQ`). (unless overriden)

You can see this

```
num1 = 0.0006000000000000001`;
num2 = 0.0006000000000000003`;
DeleteDuplicates[{num1, num2}, (#1 === #2) &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Which is same as

```
DeleteDuplicates[{num1, num2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But

```
DeleteDuplicates[{num1, num2}, (#1 == #2) &]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

`SameQ` checks the two objects are identical in the sense <strike>that they occupy same memory location</strike> they have identical `FullForm`

[image]

While for `==`

[image]

So when comparing numbers, use `==` and when comparing symbolic expressions use `===`

Comment: @"SameQ checks the two objects are identical in the sense that they occupy same memory location" Not quite following the reasoning behind this statement, but I'd say that is not the case.

Answer (score 7):

From the help of Equal ( "==" ): "Numbers with machine precision (MachinePrecision) or greater are considered equal if they differ in at most their last seven binary digits."

As Nasser already mentioned, "DeleteDuplicates"  uses "SameQ". From the help of "SameQ": "SameQ requires exact correspondence between expressions, except that it still considers Real numbers equal if they differ in their last binary digit."

Now, as "==" is less strict than "===" you get:

```
num1 == num2

True
```

and

```
num1 === num2 

False
```

Finally, consider the binary representation of num1 and num2 (note that $MachinePrecision on my machine is:15.954589770191003 )

```
num1 = 0.0006000000000000001`15.954589770191003;
num2 = 0.0006000000000000003`15.954589770191003;
BaseForm[num1, 2]
BaseForm[num2, 2]
```

[image]

As you see, the numbers differ in the last 3 digits.

Comment: Nice. You need to copy and paste result of $MachinePrecision to see the full value.

Answer (score 3):

**Warning!!!** If you evaluate this your believe in logical reasoning may be ruined ;-)

```
n1 = 0.59999999999999993;
n2 = 0.6000000000000001;
n3 = 0.6000000000000002;

{n1 == n2 == n3}
{n1 === n2, n2 === n3, n1 === n3}
```

---

> `{True}`
>
> `{True, True, False}`

Clue:

> Real numbers are considered `SameQ` if they differ only in their last binary digit
>
> (the statement is not phrased well, it should be understood so that they can differ by +/- 1 least significant bit)
>
>
> `RealDigits[n1, 2]`
>
> `RealDigits[n2, 2]`
>
> `RealDigits[n3, 2]`

Comment: This is why it's important to be aware of multi-arg SameQ: `n1 === n2 === n3 (*False*)`. SameQ isn't always transitive when it comes to numerical quantities and the multi-arg use case can account for this.

Comment: @Sjoerd Smit: It is not property of `SameQ` alone, it is similar with `Equal` used on reals numbers.